# Get All team members from DevOps Scrum team with roles

Tags: azure-devops, devops, power-automate, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on a project where I need to retrieve Product Owner, Scrum Master, QA Lead, Dev Lead and Scrum Team Area Path from Azure DevOps. I am open to technologies like Power Automate, Python, Power Virtual Agent etc. I tried with REST API Endpoints but unable to fetch details like Roles of members and area path. I was able to retrieve Scrum team name and total members list for few scrum teams only but could not find exact roles and area path for all scrum teams.

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried with REST API Endpoints but unable to fetch details like Roles of members and area path. I was able to retrieve Scrum team name and total members list for few scrum teams only but could not find exact roles and area path for all scrum teams.

I have also tried to built power automate flow with HTTP request by entering endpoint API but it doesn't pull roles and area path. Only I get is Team names and that too not all teams.

https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/projects/projectid/teams/teamID/members?api-version=7.1-preview.2

Comment: How are you storing the user's role on the project? Azure DevOps does not have a concept of "Scrum Master" or "Product Owner" as a user's role. You would need to define the user's role through some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Bu default Azure DevOps does not contain `Role` property for team members.

However you may use capacities ([Determine and set sprint capacity in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops)) to define main activities and then use REST API [Get Capacities With Identity Ref And Totals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/get-capacities-with-identity-ref-and-totals?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to export this information.